# Express-validator 6.0.1 - Validating schema with checkSchema middleware

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am using express-validator to perform my backend validation on the server side and so far so good, until I am faced with a situation where I wanted to validate schemas based on the user choice on the front end. Below is what my code looks like.

### shopRoutes.js

```
router.post('create-product', oneOf([checkSchema.cars, checkSchema.events]), (req, res, next) => {}
```

### schemas

```
checkSchema.cars = { 
 title: {
        in: ['body'],
        isEmpty: {
            errorMessage: "Le champs titre est obligatoire, veuillez saisire un titre."
        },
        isLength: {
            options: { min: 3, max: 50 },
            errorMessage: "Le titre doit avoir au minimum 3 characteres et au plus 50 characteres"
        },
        trim: true,
        escape: true
    }
}

checkSchema.event = {
 location: {
        in: ['body'],
        isEmpty: {
            negated: true,
            errorMessage: "Le champs lieu est requis, veuillez selectionner un lieu afin de continuer!"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that no matter what the user choice is, creating an event or a car, express-validator will validate both of them instead of either one as it's what I understood what oneOf does. I have looked around and I saw that an issue was open since 2019 in that regards but nothing since.

Someone has found a workaround or a solution that could help me please? Thank you!